# Show when bounties end when browsing through questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties

When looking through the list of questions, it would be nice if the ones with bounties could show when the bounty is due to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does happen, on the homepage -- anything in the top (n), it is sorted in the order of the bounties ending soonest, with the bounty that is closest to expiring on top.

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured

That's the expected place to browse for "bounties that are ending soonest", not the full question list.

Comment: While I agree with what you've said, it'd still be nice to see how long a bounty has to go before it expires from the question list (even within the featured tab). Maybe a tooltip on the bounty amount (blue +100 in the above screenshot)?

Comment: Think of it as an advert "Answer this question well, and you could recieve your bounty in under 2 hours!"